# Recv call get empty data

Tags: c, sockets, unix, recv

I'm learning to work with sockets in c.
Here is my code:

```
void work_with_client(int client_sock){
    char buff[10] = {0};

    while(1){
            kv_log_message("\tWork with client\n");
            int is_received = recv(client_sock, buff, 10, 0); 
            if(is_received < 0){ 
                    perror("Received failed");
            } else {
                    printf("RESPONSE: %s\n", buff);
            }   
            printf("RESPONSE %d\n", is_received);

            sleep(1);
    }   
}
```

When I connect through telnet to this server and immediately disconnect, server print this lines:

```
    Work with client
RESPONSE: 
RESPONSE 10
    Work with client
RESPONSE: 
RESPONSE 10
    Work with client
RESPONSE: 
RESPONSE 10
    Work with client
RESPONSE: 
RESPONSE 10
    Work with client
RESPONSE: 
RESPONSE 1
    Work with client
RESPONSE: 
RESPONSE 0
    Work with client
```

And I don't get why first 4 `recv` calls get full size of buffer data (I don't write anything to the socket from client perspective).
Any suggestions?
P.S. Run on Mac OS X Yosemite

**UPDATE:** i test my program on Linux, and recv call always return 0 in my case, so probably the problem in telnet on Mac OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i get it, `telnet` on Mac OS X (Yosemite) send some data if you just close terminal without proper closing connection through telnet itself (i.e. put escape character and `quit` command).

Honestly I don't know is it bug or some kind of debug behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When `recv()` returned `0` this indicates the other side shut down the connection.

From [`man recv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> [...] The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

You then might like to exit the `while()` loop.

---

Update:

Also the code might invoke undefined behaviour by passing a non `0`-terminated "string" to `printf()`.

To fix this read one `char` less to `buff` then it's size and add the `0`-terminator.

```
    while (1)
    {
        ssize_t is_received = recv(client_sock, buff, sizeof buff - 1, 0); 
        if (is_received < 0){ 
                perror("Received failed");
                break;
        } else if (is_received == 0) {
                printf("%s\n", "peer shutdown");
                break;
        }

        buff[is_received] = '\0';
        printf("RESPONSE: %s\n", buff);
   }
```

Comment: Yeap, but what about first 4 calls to recv which return `10` value although client already close connection

Comment: Maybe Telnet sent some negotiation stuff.

Comment: Your update is not solve the problem, now it shows me `9` value instead of `10` =)